# Safari animation glitches - white flashes

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, css-animations

I am having issues with Safari with white flashes and random shaking during animations. Any ideas of what is causing this?

Video of error: https://brotsky.viewscreencasts.com/e48df175b5fe12f680ab0ea7bd5bc51f

URL: http://alchemy.brotskydesigns.com/new/

The issue is only on Safari, works great on Chrome and Firefox. The website also crashes when you zoom in on some "floors" on my iPhone 4s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue! The issue had to do with using 3d and 2d elements together (the second floor as a text element that is using a matrix3d perspective).

I edited my CSS from:

```
html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #d7d7d0;
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    perspective: 800;
    -webkit-transform: transform;
}
```

to

```
html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #d7d7d0;
}
```

This fixed the issue on Safari and iOS and the matrix3d perspective remained the same.